# test data verification or behavior verification

Tags: java, junit

I've a RESTful webservice which has rest layer - service layer - dao layer. This service result different result set in different scenario like-  customer with  list of incidents, customer with a particular type of incident, customer with no incident, no customer etc.

I'm writing Junit test case for DAO layer. I want to mock-up the database. Should i test result set (state) in my unit test case or should i test behavior of result set ? Does it make sense to prepare test data (result set) for different test scenario and assert on them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just verify your behaviour.

If you were to mock your DB - maybe like this, using Mockito:

```
when(mockedDAO.getResults(onSomeParameters).thenReturn(yourStubbedReturnSet);
```

then you'd be stubbing your DAO out to return a cooked result-set, for which there's no value in asserting anything on.

So just verify that .getResults() makes the call to the DB with the parameters you expect.  Your DAO should be doing no more, so there should be no more to test.

oh ... and write your test first :)  You will have a much easier time figuring out how to test your code.